# php o javascript para descargar archivo apk desde mi servidor

Tags: php, javascript, apk

despues de googlear llego hasta aqui,

Tengo mi pagina `index.html` en el que tengo un boton para abrir otra pagina de 'gracias por la descarga'

```
<a href="http://mipagina.com/graciaspordescargar.php" target="_blank" class="download-btn"></a>
```

esta ultima pagina deberia descargar 'automaticamente' mi archivo `app.apk`

pero no encuentro la manera, he probado con codigos como este:

```
graciaspordescargar.php

<head>
..
<?php
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="app.apk"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    readfile('app.apk');
    ?>
...
</head>
```

pero el archivo apk se 'corrompe' en el lado del cliente al descargar.

Quisiera ver la manera de descargar automaticamente al abrir la segunda pagina, ya sea con php, javascript o alguna otra manera.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Porque no simplemente usar el atributo download y colocas la ruta directa de tu apk en el servidor??, realmente mo necesitarias un script php ni nada de eso...

Comment: si necesitaba otra pagina para estadisticas de Pixel facebook

Answer (score 0):

Por si le sirve a alguien,

he buscado una pagina similar y presionando F12 me puse a ver el codigo en el navegador,

esto hace que se descargue automaticamente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.setTimeout(function(){
window.location = "http://mipagina.com/app.apk";    },1000);
</script>
```

el numero 1000 es la cantidad de milisegundos que se espera antes de descargar el archivo en cuestion